# How to slide child dive left to disappear and replace with a new child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 2 `<div>`s inside a parent container like;

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content" style="background-color: #CC0033;">static content</div>
  <div class="content" style="background-color: #FF6600;">dynamic content</div>
</div>
```

The first child div (static content) contain some text. When I click a trigger link, it will slide left and disapperar. I have gone it using jquery `animate()` like;

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
  $(".content").animate({ "margin-left": "-100px" }, "slow");
});
```

When this slide out, it should be followed by another div, which has the same class, so that it looks same. The old slide thus will be vanished away and the parent container will have the new div. This event may continue whenever I click the trigger. Or for another example, on every 5 seconds, the current div will be slide left, followed with new div. The divs may contain a unique text, say, like a number. The number increments each time.

I think a new  containing all info except text (content), which varies may be appended each time, but I am not sure will this solve my problem. Is this possible?

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/mmL2U/)** is the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $ct = $('.container')
    $("#trigger").click(function(){
        $ct.children(".content:first").animate({ "margin-left": "-100px" }, "slow", function(){
            $(this).remove()
        });
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YEjUE/)

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this might be that when #trigger is clicked, the click function not only just modify the style of the static content, but also move the dynamic content to the left by changing the margin-left. 
It might looks like:

```
$('#trigger').click(function(){
    $(/*static content*/).animate({"margin-left": "-100px"}, "slow");
    $(/*dynamic content*/).animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, "slow");
});
```